# Understanding a C++ codebase by generating UML - tools&methology

Tags: c++, uml, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

I think there are many tools that can generate UML and similar diagrams   from C++ (source-code), but I think it is not so easy to make sense of what you get out?

I am looking for good tools/procedures.

For example I might want to see the GUI-layer and how it is separated (or not from the rest). Think the tools should somehow help me detect packages, and also let me manually organize it.

Answer (score 2):

Free: Doxygen
Paid: Rational Rose

Comment: I think Doxygen only analyses the code, and that I would need to annotate the code itself?

Comment: What would Rational Rose do more than producing UML?